# Securing communication between mobile app and backend server

Tags: android, ios, performance, security, rest

What are the best practices for securing data communication between mobile client app and the REST based backed server. 
Given that SSL certificate is being used what are other best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice really depends on what specifically you are doing.  Generally speaking best practice is to use HTTPS/SSL/TLS and issue the REST calls through that secured connection.  The SSL will verify that the server is who they claim, and optionally the client.  It will also negotiate a symmetric private key that is used to encrypt the remainder of the conversation.  It is by far the most efficient, safe, and well established best practice out there.

If you are without SSL certificates and still need security, you can use a pre-shared private key.  However maintaining/updating this key can be difficult without opening yourself up for attack.  Additionally you'll need to have a *different key* for every client, which means your server needs to have them all.

There are already great SSL implementations for both Android and iOS.  Those are what you should use.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm aware of SSL secured connection. What I was trying to understand - what are additional methods and practices used developers out there to capture and communicate sensitive data (like username, password) to my backed server. I guess I should have made it more clear in the question itself

Comment: AFAIK, there are no other "best practice" methods available.  Depending on specific situations, there are things you can do, but only when you can't use SSL should you consider them.  Do you have a specific situation in mind?